# Stopping at end of file

Tags: c, loops, eof, file-handling

I have a problem getting my loop to stop reading the file after the end. How can I get it to stop after the last line and go to the next line of code? Also I would like the incremented score to stop with the loop and the final result be written into a file, can anyone help? Thank you

```
do {
    system("cls");
    i = 0;
    printf("\tPortal Examination\n\tEnter Faculty name.:");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s", f_name);
    printf("\n\tEnter Course.:");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s", course_text);
    printf("\n\tEnter ID.:");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s", r_query);
    k = strlen(r_query);
    strcat(f_name,"101stud.txt");
    strcat(course_text,"101exam.txt");
    f_course = fopen(f_name, "rb");

    system("cls");
    printf("\tPortal Examination");
    printf("\n\n..:: Searching for '%s' \n===================================================\n",r_query);
    while (fread(&stud, sizeof(stud), 1, f_course) == 1) {
        for (j = 0; j <= k; j++) {
            s_rollno[j] = stud.stud_rollno[j];
        }
        s_rollno[j]='\0';

        if (stricmp(s_rollno,r_query) == 0) {
            system("pause");
            //*****write exams****
            f_exam = fopen(course_text, "rb");
            while (fread(&numbers, sizeof(numbers), 1, f_exam) != EOF) {
                system("cls");
                printf("\n\tAnswer all Questions:\n\t%s\n\t",numbers.question);
                fflush(stdin);
                scanf("%s", a_query);
                if (stricmp(numbers.answer, a_query) == 0)
                    s_result += 5;
                printf("%s has %d score\n\t", r_query, s_result);
                system("pause");
            }
            break;
            i++;
            if (i % 4 == 0) {
                printf("..::Press any key to continue...");
                getch();
            }
        }
    }
    if (i == 0)
        printf("\n..::No match found!");
    else
        printf("\n..:: %d match(s) found.",i);
    fclose(f_course);
    printf("\n..:: Search Again?\n\n\t[1] Yes\t\t[0] No\n\t");
    scanf("%d",&ch);
} while (ch == 1);
break;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems with your code:

- Do not use `fflush(stdin);`.  The behavior is undefined.  It may read pending characters from `stdin` on your system, but it is not the portable way to do so. Indeed there is no portable way to do so.  It is probably not necessary either.
- You do not test the return value of `scanf`.  `scanf` returns the number of fields correctly read from `stdin`.  If the field is not read correctly, the value in the output variable is indeterminate, so you should either retry or abort.
- `scanf("%s", f_name);` is risky: unexpectedly long input will cause a buffer overflow and your program may crash or have potentially harmful behavior.  This kind of bug can be used by hackers to penetrate a system.  Use `scanf("%39s", f_name);` if `f_name` is an array of 40 chars.
- The code you posted does not show the definitions of `f_name`, `stud`... and many more variables or structures.  We cannot verify if your usage is correct. For example, concatenation performed by `strcat(f_name,"101stud.txt");` can cause undefined behavior if `f_name` is not large enough.
- the `break;` statement in the middle of the code only breaks from the inner `while` loop, not the outer `do / while` loop.  The `i++;` statement that follows is never reached.
- The final `scanf("%d",&ch);` may fail if a non digit character is present in the input stream.  In this case, `ch` has indeterminate content.  Therefore the test on `ch == 1` is not reliable.